# Background positioning - CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Please see attached screenshot
[image]

The background is a bit off in both IE and chrome (although it was working before? hence the exact numbers??), although in ffox it looked allright..

Here is the code for what I thought was very straight forward... am I missing something?

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background:url(../images/body-bg.jpg) no-repeat ;
    background-position: -20px top;
}
```

And an IE fix

```
    
    #wrapper{ background-position: -21px top; }
```

---

I actually just want it centered - so I'm just going to say "center top"

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is (to me, anyway). Can you say what 'a bit off' means?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of numeric values (-21px) and keywords (top) was not allowed in CSS 2.0 and the support is rather unreliable. Try `-21px 0px`.